# Porque é que mar é masculino em português mas feminino em francês?

Tags: etimologia, linguística

Mar é [masculino em português](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/mar), mas [feminino em francês](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/mer).
Ambas as palavras vêm do latim `mare`.

Porque é que não têm géneros iguais?
Será porque a palavra latina mare [tem género neutro](http://latin-dictionary.net/definition/26443/mare-maris)?

Comment: é masculino ou feminino em espanhol

Comment: Outras palavras que podem se encaixar na mesma dúvida (ou talvez não): "Água", "cor" e "dor" são feminino em PT e masculino em ES. Já "sangue" é masculino em PT e feminino em ES. (Desculpa, mas eu não sei Francês :) )

Comment: Exemplos noutras línguas românticas servem igualmente, @Math, obrigado. :)

Comment: @Math "agua" em espanhol é feminino: http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=agua

Comment: @Nathaniel tem razão. É que se fala "El agua", mas é porque "agua" começa com "a". Achei a explicação aqui: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/55

Comment: Temos também `alma` que em espanhol é masculino e `leite` que é feminino.

Comment: @aldux No castelhano a palavra [*alma* é sempre feminina, sem exceção](http://lema.rae.es/drae/?val=alma): p.ex. *el alma pura y ligera*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sim, é porque a palavra era de género neutro em latim: p.ex. *mare magnum*.<sup>[1](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/mare#Latim),[2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mare#Latin)</sup> Quando esse género foi perdido, diferentes [línguas descendentes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mare#Descendants) escolheram diferentes géneros para si:

- LA: mare/maris [“illud”] (neu.)
- IT: il mare (masc.)
- RO: la mare (fem.)
- FR: la mer (fem.)
- OC: la mar (fem.)
- CA: el mar (masc.)
- PT: o mar (masc.)
- GA: o mar (masc.)
- ES: el mar / la mar (ambos)
- AST: el mar / la mar (ambos)

A diferença entre o catalão e o occitano é algo surpreendente, dado o quão perto esses dois idiomas normalmente são.

Curiosamente, em castelhano e asturiano a palavra é normalmente masculina em sentidos concretos, mas às vezes é feminina em sentidos mais abstratos ou poéticos: *el Mar Mediterránneo* mas *en alta mar*.

Comment: Interessante......